# VueJS Stop observer watching a temporary variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, observers

I am having a problem with VueJS and Observer objects. I am assigning part of my object to a temporary variable to use later. Then resassign the original part of my object with new data and after 8 seconds revert it back to its original state that I stored in my temporary variable.

I have this Object linked to a list view which renders these 2 different states differently.

I want to stop the observer from observing my temporary variable but I cant work out how.

Below is the code I currently have:

```
var temporary = core_data.map_data[data.selected]; //This is the variable I dont want to be observed.

core_data.map_data[data.selected].colour = data.colour;
core_data.map_data[data.selected].message = data.message;
core_data.map_data[data.selected].type = "ping";
setTimeout(
    function () {
        core_data.map_data[data.selected] =temporary;

        // console.log(core_data.map_data);
    }, 8000);
```

Comment: which var do you want to not watch?

Comment: temporary. I shall update my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want reactivity in vuejs `data(){}` object, you can sort of 'clone' and make a copy of the object using JSON's [`parse/stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) methods. ex:

```
 var copy = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.original ) );
```

You can now modify `copy` and it won't update your original data property.

After you are done modifying it, you can still update the `this.original` as easy as assigning it the value of your copy object.

[`jsfiddle - demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/oj0ynrtw/)

Comment: Thank you very much that is helpful. I am new to VueJS so im probably doing a lot things wrong. Its just this also using some other system which dynamicly change the page as it stays open via sockets.

Comment: No problems, I'm glad to help. Did this answer solve your problem though?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lodash.js` javascript library, `cloneDeep` method, because JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) will not work for some large lists or large data, and its not effective

https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep

Example

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// => false
```